# mysql like query with check of values in comma separated data

Tags: mysql

I have a table with data like this

```
+-------+---------------------+------------------------------------------------+--------------------+
|  id   |        name         |                   movieyears                   | length(movieyears) |
+-------+---------------------+------------------------------------------------+--------------------+
| 85530 | Nargis Fakhri       | [2011,2013,2014]                               |                 16 |
| 26683 | Nawazuddin Siddiqui | [1999,2006,2007,2009,2010,2012,2013,2014,2015] |                 46 |
| 14508 | Aditi Rao Hydari    | [2009,2011,2012,2013,2014]                     |                 26 |
+-------+---------------------+------------------------------------------------+--------------------+
```

Challenge is to find the rows for which the actors were only active in past 4 years and not in any other years, so essentially a good query should return only the first row of 'Nargis Fakhri' and not of any other actor, I know about Find_In_set but that's to find if actor existed for one particular year.

Comment: 1. See normalization. That's all.

Comment: Don't store multiple values in a single column.

Comment: I wish i could, I am out of option here, and Yes i do know normalization, I am just not in state to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution would be quite as ugly as the table design...

```
select
  id, name
from
  TheTable
where
  movieyears <> '[]' and
  replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(movieyears, '2011', ''), '2012', ''), '2013', ''), '2014', ''), ',', '') = '[]'
```

Comment: an ugly code needs an ugly mate, couldn't agree more :)

Answer (score 0):

As a note, your years seem to be ordered.  If this is the case:

```
select t.*
from tablewithdata t
where substring_index(movieyears, ',', 1) >= '2011';
```